# How do I add line breaks after each tag in the xml

Tags: php, xml

I'm working on my php script to generating XML to save the XML file in my web host. I want to make some lines breaks. I need to add line breaks for each tags after the `</channel>`, but it will not break for each line in the xml.

Here's the xml output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<tv generator-info-name="www.mysite.com/xmltv">
<channel id="ABC FAMILY">
   <display-name>ABC FAMILY</display-name>
   <programme channel="ABC FAMILY" start="s1" stop="e1">
       <title lang="en">program title</title>
       <sub-title lang="en">sub title</sub-title>
       <desc lang="en">program description1</desc>
       <category lang="en">some category</category>
   </programme>
</channel> 
\n

<channel id="CBS">
   <display-name>CBS</display-name>
   <programme channel="CBS" start="s1" stop="e1">
       <title lang="en">program title</title>
       <sub-title lang="en">sub title</sub-title>
       <desc lang="en">program description1</desc>
       <category lang="en">some category</category>
   </programme>
</channel> 
\n





<?php

function db_connect()
{
  define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
  define('DB_USER', 'myusername');
  define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword');
  define('DB_DATABASE', 'mydbname');

  $errmsg_arr = array();
  $errflag = false;
  $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

  if(!$link) 
  {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
  if(!$db) 
  {
    die("Unable to select database");
  }
}
db_connect();

  function clean($var)
  {
    return mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($var));
  } 
  $channels = clean($_GET['channels']);
  $id = clean($_GET['id']);

  if($errflag) 
  {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    echo implode('<br />',$errmsg_arr);
  }
  else 
  {
    $insert = array();

    if(isset($_GET['channels'])) 
    {
      $insert[] = 'channels = \'' . clean($_GET['channels']) .'\'';
    }
    if(isset($_GET['id'])) 
    {
      $insert[] = 'id = \'' . clean($_GET['id']) . '\'';
    }

    if(!$channels && ! $id) 
    {
      $qrytable1="SELECT id, channels, links, streams FROM tvguide";
      $result1=mysql_query($qrytable1) or die('Error:<br />' . $qry . '<br />' . mysql_error());


      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
      {
        // fake some example data. the actual data would be retrieved from a database query
        $data[] = array('channel_id'=>$row['channels'],
        'display_name'=>$row['channels'],
        'program_id'=>123,'start'=>'s1','stop'=>'e1',
        'title'=>'program title',
         'sub_title'=>'sub title',
         'description'=>'program description1',
         'category'=>'some category');



        // build the xml    
        $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<tv generator-info-name="www.mysite.com/xmltv">';
        $last_channel = null; // used to detect when the channel changes
        foreach($data as $arr)
        {
            if($last_channel != $arr['channel_id'])
            {
                // the channel changed
                if($last_channel != null){
                    // not the first channel, close out the previous channel
                    $xml .= '
</channel> \n
';
                }
                // start a new channel
                $xml .= "
<channel id=\"{$arr['channel_id']}\">";
                $xml .= "
   <display-name>{$arr['display_name']}</display-name>";
                $last_channel = $arr['channel_id'];
            }
            // output the program info under each channel
            $xml .= "
   <programme channel=\"{$arr['channel_id']}\" start=\"{$arr['start']}\" stop=\"{$arr['stop']}\">";
            // i don't see a program id in this definition, but it likely needs one
            $xml .= "
       <title lang=\"en\">{$arr['title']}</title>";
            $xml .= "
       <sub-title lang=\"en\">{$arr['sub_title']}</sub-title>";
            $xml .= "
       <desc lang=\"en\">{$arr['description']}</desc>";
            $xml .= "
       <category lang=\"en\">{$arr['category']}</category>";
            $xml .= "
   </programme>";
        }
        if($last_channel != null)
        {
            // close out the previous channel if any
            $xml .= '
</channel>';
        }
     }

   }
   $xml .= '
</tv>';
   // output the xml to the browser in this example, write $xml to a file here...
   header("Content-Type: text/xml");
   echo $xml;
   $handle = fopen("myChannel.xml", "w"); 
   fwrite ($handle, $xml);
 }
?>
```

Can you please tell me how I can break for each line after the `</channel>` tag?

Comment: Quixrick has the solution to your issue.  While I understand that you have written the code and it probably works, reinventing the wheel with php doesn't make sense when you have libraries like http://us2.php.net/simplexml

Comment: I agree; SimpleXML in PHP makes things really easy when constructing, modifying or parsing XML from within PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\n` does not work in single quotes.  Use double quotes instead:

```
$xml .= "
</channel> \n
";
```

Comment: thanks for this. I have added the double quotes in that line, but it did not break the line after `</channel>` tag. It will only show the line break using view source, but not for the xml root. Do you know why?

Comment: You're trying to display the XML on a web page in addition to writing to a file?  Of course in HTML, the break would be the `<br>` not the `\n`.  So if you want to do both, you have a couple of options.  You can set a delimeter that you can then go through and replace later (one for the web and one for the file) or you can just make 2 versions.  `$xml .= "</channel>\n"; $xml_web .= "<channel><br>";`  If you need help with either of those, let me know.  I may have misunderstood what you are trying to do also.  So feel free to correct me.

Comment: Yes, I'm displaying the xml in my php. I want to break the line after `</channel>`, I tried to use the code you suggest me to use but I have got an error `error on line 132 at column 6: Opening and ending tag mismatch: channel line 0 and tv`. The source I use `</channel><br>;'. Please see the picture of my example xml source: http://imageshack.com/a/img836/1483/wlxo.png

Comment: Ahhh, thanks for including the screenshot.  Well what you are seeing there is the browser's interpretation of the XML and you cannot change that.  If you go to a different browser and look at the same page, it will look entirely different.  If you really want to display the XML the way it looks, you'd want to use something like `htmlentities`.  Here, meet me over at collabedit.  http://collabedit.com/tgvry

Comment: Oh ok thanks for your help anyway. I did not realise that I got an xml from the website I downloaded and I did not realise that I cannot break the line in the xml, so thanks anyway.